# Non-trivial real function such that $|f(x) - f(ax+b)|$ depends only on $a$ and $b$

Tags: functions, uniform-continuity

Let $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$ be constants.

Find a (non-trivial) continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(ax+b)|
\end{align*} depends only upon $a$ and $b$.

Comment: It seems to me that such an $f$ would have to be a constant function. Do you have a non-constant example?

Comment: @quasi I think $a$ and $b$ are fixed. In that case you can find nonconstant examples. This should be clarified though.

Comment: @user420261 what would non constant examples be for fixed $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @Brock I was thinking of something like $\log_a(x+\frac{b}{a-1})$ but on second thought that isn't defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. So I'm not sure.

Comment: The question is unclear to me.  Do you want an $f$, depending on $a,b$ such that the given expression is constant?  Or do you want one $f$ such that the 3 variable function $(x,a,b)\mapsto |f(x)-f(ax+b)|$ depends only on $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\vert f(x)-f(ax+b)\vert = g(a,b)$ for all $x,a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Then for all $x$ we have
$$\vert f(x) - f(0) \vert = g(0,0)$$
and so
$$f(x) = f(0)\pm g(0,0)$$
In order for $f$ to be continuous, we need $f(x) = f(0)+g(0,0)$ or $f(x) = f(0)-g(0,0)$. In either case, $f$ is constant.

Comment: @vadim123 That function is not continuous